# How to read fixed length file in java

Tags: java, parsing, reader

I’m reading flat files in java with fixed length 
I’m new to this can anyone help me out how to do fixed length reader ?

Comment: Binary data or text? A FileInputStream with a fixed sized `byte[]` would be a starting point.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a question-and-answer site. It is not a "help" site, because that would require a different format, not "question-and-answer". Please read [why "can someone help me" not a real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please do some research, create a program, and if you have any specific, answerable questions about it, you are welcome to post here.

Comment: It will be text file @Joop Eggen

Answer (score 1):

When it is a text file, with fixed length *lines*, a normal reader suffices.

This assumes that there is a newline at the end of each record.

```
List<MyRecord> result = new ArrayList<>();

Path file = Paths.get("C:/Import/20190308.txt");
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();

Files.lines(path, charset)
    .filter(line -> line.length() != 142)
    .forEach(line -> {
        MyRecord record = new MyRecord();
        record.id = Long.parseLong(line.substring(0, 10).trim());
        record.name = line.substring(10, 50).trim();
        record.age = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(50, 53).trim());
        ...
        result.add(record);
    });
```

The `String.trim()` removing the padding spaces before ("Mary    ") and after (" 89"). The `String.substring(position, nextPosition)` picking the fixed field.

The read line is without newline character(s) - `\r\n` or `\n` in general.
There is a check on the line length (here 142). This is the length in `char`s, but most likely is the length in bytes too, as fixed length records probably are in a single byte charset.

---

For some custom class MyRecord mirroring a CSV line:

```
public class MyRecord {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public int age;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your support, but it's not helping me out

Comment: can you please elaborate more on it.

Comment: I added a bit more. Try reading only the lines (maybe from a reduced small sample file) and start working from there, checking the line length. Debug.